# Shopify appi REST request failed: "Not Found" for some requests

Tags: php, shopify-api

creating connection

```
 Context::initialize(
            $this->key,
            $this->secret,
            $_ENV['SHOPIFY_API_SCOPES'],
            $_ENV['SHOPIFY_URL'],
            new FileSessionStorage('/tmp/php_sessions'),
            '2023-01',
        );

$id = uniqid();
$shopDomain = $this->url;
$isOnline = false;
$state = bin2hex(random_bytes(16));

$session = new \Shopify\Auth\Session($id, $shopDomain, $isOnline, $state);
$session->setAccessToken($this->token);

$this->test_session = $session;
```

get fulfilments :

```
$fulfillment = Fulfillment::create(
        $this->test_session,
        $fulfillmentData,
        ['order_id' => $order->getId()]
    );
```

return object

but

```
$fulfillment = new Fulfillment($this->test_session);
$fulfillment->message = "The package was shipped this morning.";
$fulfillment->notify_customer = false;
$fulfillment->tracking_info = [
    "number" => 1562678,
    "url" => "https://www.my-shipping-company.com",
    "company" => "my-shipping-company"
];


/** @var Product $item */
foreach ($order->getLineItems() as $item) {

    $fulfillment->line_items_by_fulfillment_order = [
        [
            "fulfillment_order_id" => $order->getId(),
            "fulfillment_order_line_items" => [
                [
                    "id" => $item->getId(),
                    "quantity" => 1
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
}


$fulfillment->save(
    true, // Update Object
);
```

give my

REST request failed: "Not Found"

I use (symfony 6, php 8.2)

```
use Shopify\Auth\OAuth;
use Shopify\Rest\Admin2023_01\Fulfillment;
use Shopify\Rest\Admin2023_01\Webhook;
use Shopify\Utils;
```

not found generated by:

```
REST request failed: "Not Found"

    Exception Logs 1 Stack Trace 

Shopify\Exception\ RestResourceRequestException
in vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Rest/Base.php (line 204)
in vendor/shopify/shopify-api/src/Rest/Base.php :: request (line 67)
Base->save(true) in src/Service/Api/ShopifyApiService.php (line 131)


in namespace Shopify\Rest;  abstract class Base protected static function request(
i dump request before send 

 pa([
            $client,
            $path,
            $params
        ]);
```

i see

(i replace details to xxx

```
  0 => Shopify\Clients\Rest {#1989 ▼
    -domain: "xxxx.myshopify.com"
    -accessToken: "xxx"
  }
  1 => "fulfillments.json"
```

Comment: Whch line specifically causes the "not found"?

Comment: i update example